# C Warning: Statement with no effect

Tags: c, for-loop, warnings

When trying to compile my prgram with:

```
gcc -pedantic -Wall -ansi
```

I get the warning: **warning: statement with no effect**

Referring to this line:

```
for(currentDirection; currentDirection <= endDirection; currentDirection++)
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`currentDirection;` does nothing.

Replace your line with

```
for(; currentDirection <= endDirection; currentDirection++)
```

Or, in case you just forgot to initialize the variable:

```
for(currentDirection = 0; currentDirection <= endDirection; currentDirection++)
```

Comment: Or perhaps it's meant to be `currentDirection = 1` given the termination criterion

Answer (score 9):

```
for(currentDirection; currentDirection <= endDirection; currentDirection++)
 // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Its saying about the above statement.
```

First statement should have an assignment, which is not happening in this case and is the reason for the warning. Make sure `currentDirection` is assigned to a valid value or it might have garbage and might later cause issues.

It is similar to when said -

```
 int i = 10 ;
 i ;   // This statement is valid but has no effect.
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience this issue comes up when you do somthing along the lines of

```
int x = 0;
for(x = 0;x < num; x++){}
```

When you are declaring your loop and you already initialize your variable, x you don't need to declare it a second time.
So either do:

```
int x = 0;
for(; x < num; x++){}
```

Or

```
int x;
for(x = 0; x < num; x++){}
```